# ADF Using Union to combine data

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to combine data from 2 data sources in ADF. The combining of data is working correctly but not in the correct order. I want to do this using union.

Below is my dataflow containing the union.

Source1 contains 1 row of data. Whereas, source2 contains multiple rows of data. When combining these rows using union this is done in a random order. However, I want the 1 row in source1 to be the first row in the sink output. Anyone know how to do this? I've tried adding the union to source1 instead but this doesn't work either.

[image]

source2 data example:

```
1110,555,666,1
1130,345,876,5
```

source1 data example:

```
uniquekey,number,id,position
```

Current Output:

```
1110,555,666,1
1130,345,876,5
uniquekey,number,id,position
```

Desired Ouput:

```
uniquekey,number,id,position
1110,555,666,1
1130,345,876,5
```

Comment: How about putting the `Union1` activity right after `Select1` activity and union with the `Select2` activity, instead of the current approach of putting the `Union1` activity right after `Select2` activity and union with the `Select1` activity?

Comment: No they gave me the same output, the 1 row is added to bottom

Comment: Have you also check out the [Union by position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union#name-and-position) option?

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: If you need to force ordering in data flows, you will need to grab control of Spark's data distribution and partitioning features. Go into the Optimize tab and set to Single Partition.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to repro your issue, where I got expected output as required. But when I tried to run this pipeline. It was generating two different files same as Source and Sink.

[image]

So I performed below steps to get required output.

Source1 file.

[image]

Source2 file.

[image]

Union Configuration as follows:

Union settings tab

[image]

Optimize tab

[image]

Inspect tab

[image]

Sink Configuration:

Do not provide filename in Sink Configuration.

[image]

In Sink configuration use Single Partition in Optimize tab.

Keep mapping in Sink Configuration as shown below:

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

[image]